# Add-hybridrunbookworker "argument group cannot be null"

Tags: azure, hybrid-runbook-worker

I'm trying to use the Add-HybridRunbookWorker cmdlet to create a hybrid worker as instructed by the [OMS Hybrid worker solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-hybrid-runbook-worker).

The issue is that I'm getting

```
Invalid argument specified. Argument group cannot be null.
```

Documentation only mentions adding `–Url $url -Key $key -GroupName $groupName` as arguments so I'm unsure what's happening.  Anyone have thoughts?

Edit:

I'm also noticing that after running the cmdlet that workers are showing up on the azure portal but are unusable.  They also cannot be removed from the on-premise computer since it's saying none are registered on that side.

Only thing I can think of is that the cmdlet references some module which I may have a different version of installed which introduced a new argument?

Answer (score 0):

fixed my issue.  I thought I was supposed to use a group name of one of the system hybrid worker groups but I actually needed to give a totally new name.

Simple fix, and obvious in hindsight.